# Перенаправление на HTTPS ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Есть метод который делает перенаправление на HTTPS  и он определяется в файле Startup

```
UseHttpsRedirection()
```

Но он работает только с версии Core 2.1. Мой хост не поддерживает еще эту версию.  Есть какие это адекватные альтернативы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    var options = new RewriteOptions()
       .AddRedirectToHttps();

    app.UseRewriter(options);
}
```

Подробнее [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=visual-studio).

Comment: пробую в состояние дебага у себя на локале, перенаправление на https есть но пишет что проверте подключение к интернету и в итоге не запускается, коментирую строки, запускается. Где тут бог может быть?

Comment: Да, перезалил сайт, все работает. Спасибо!